# Which version of Python did pip or easy_install refer to by default?

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I am a non-programmer who started to learn Python. My Mac OS X Yosemite shipped with Python 2.7.6. I installed Python 3.4.2 too. If I use `pip` or `easy_install` in the terminal to install a package, how do I know which Python I installed the package in? It seems Python 3.4.2 shipped with `pip` and `easy_install`, but I think Python 2.7.6 may also have some version of `pip` or `easy_install`. I know my system can have both versions of Python, but can it have multiple versions of `pip` or `easy_install`?

Comment: Yes, it can have multiple versions of each.  `which pip` should list the path to the executable which is the default in your `$PATH` and it will probably be obvious which installation it belongs to.

Comment: @BrianCain yes, but it might be located in `/usr/local/bin`, for example, so that wouldn't give much info...

Comment: ...ok, right, I wasn't verbose enough -- `readlink $(which pip)` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easy way around it - use `pip2` or `pip2.7` or `pip-2.7` for Python 2, and `pip3` or `pip3.4` or `pip-3.4` for Python 3. Both version ship with `easy_install`, but Python 2 does not contain `pip` by default - you have to install it yourself.

Comment: thanks, what you said is right for my condition,I find only my python 3.4.2 has a pip3, my python 2.7.6 which shipped with yosemite did not have pip, that means if I Type "pip3 install somepakage", I will install that package to python 3.4.2, the python tutorial books I read tend to use easy_install, if I type "easy_instal" in my terminal, will I install the package into 2.7.6 or 3.4.2 ? maybe I can try it, but I'm afraid to ruin my terminal.

Comment: @Sniper_3B I wouldn't use `easy_install` at all, mostly b/c you can't uninstall with it, and it's quite outdated. Follow the instructions [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) to download `get-pip.py`, then install it with Python 2. You'll now be able to install packages into both versions, using `pip2` for Py2 and `pip3` for Py3.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip -V
```

to find the default python version

If you have multiple versions, they will usually be named `pip2` for Python2, `pip3` for Python3 etc

You really shouldn't be using easy_install anymore

Comment: I find I can type pip3, but not pip, because the python 2.7.6 shipped with Mac OS X may not include pip, but the 3.4.2 I download from the Python dot org include pip3, but for easy_install, it make no sense to type easy_install3 or easy_install2, to keep coherent with the python tutorial books I read, if I type "easy_install somepakage", will I install it to 2.7.6 or 3.4.2?